# Pandas, extract values of specific column based on other column's value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
            Item  Weight  Bags    Must  quantity  must quantity  bags length  length assigned bag
0     planes bag    8.50  planes   v       1              1          6                None
1  Full Bandolera   3.76  planes   v       3              2          6                None
2  tail             0.30  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None
3  central wing     1.08  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None
4  engine           0.44  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None
5  height steer     0.12  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None
6  dihedral         0.40  planes  <NA>     3              2          6                None   
7  pods bag         8.72  pods     v       1              1          4                None
8  Pod              1.74  pods     v       3              2          4                None
9  optic            0.86  pods     v       2              2          4                None
10 thermal          1.20  pods     v       3              2          4                None
11 Encryption Cable 0.20  Ground  <NA>    1              0          25                None
                          System,
```

I want to extract all values in the Item and weight column based on the value in the bags length column.

```py
must_pods = cls.df.loc[
            cls.df[DfConsts.ITEM, DfConsts.WEIGHT]
            if cls.df.loc[cls.df[DfConsts.BAGS_COLUMN_LENGTH] == BagsStringLength.GROUND_SYSTEM_LEN]
```

I know pandas doesn't accept if statement like this, but I don't know the right syntax for that operation.

Comment: Looks like a simple loc: `df.loc[df['bags length'] == 6, ['Item', 'Weight']]`

Comment: If you need a data frame _for each_ value of `bags length`, use groupby: `g = df.groupby('bags length')[['Item', 'Weigth']]` and then iterate through `g`: `for bag_length, sub_df in g: print(bag_length, sub_sd)`